# multiple user input with their second input

Tags: python, exponent

I want the user's base input to be raised to the power the user input in the power.

```
def raise_power():
    base = input("Base: ")
    power = input("Power: ")
    for index in range(power) and range(base):
        base * power
print(raise_power())
```

Comment: ```base**power?```

Comment: Why do you have a for loop?  If that's in a function, just do `return int(base)**int(power)`.

Comment: Please can you explain what your input should look like and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
base = input("Base: ")
power = input("Power: ")
num = int(base)**int(power)
print(num)
```

Explanation - You don't need a for loop to iterate over your base and power variables. `*` is the multiplication syntax and therefore your program is multiplying your base and power. In order to raise the base to a power, we use the `**` syntax.

You can read [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-do-math-in-python-3-with-operators#:%7E:text=The%20**%20operator%20in%20Python,raised%20to%20the%203rd%20power.) article about the different math operators in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,without the for loop:
´´´
v=int(base)**int(power)
return v
´´´